# How to change color of theme in wordpress using command

Tags: wordpress, command-line, wordpress-theming

I would like to change current theme color by using command in wordpress.

Is there option there? By using DB command or any other.

Thanks in advance,

Amol Rajhans

Comment: you cant change css of wordpress using command line

Comment: When we changes color from UI from customize => colors => background, then data is saved into DB wp_posts table the background related data is saved like 
`
{
    "shapely::background_color": {
        "value": "#dd3333",
        "type": "theme_mod",
        "user_id": 1,
        "date_modified_gmt": "2018-06-26 09:42:36"
    }
}
`
And in index file i found 
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { background-color: #dd3333; }
</style>